# Dynamically add rows to word table in vb.net application

Tags: vb.net

I am running this code to open a word document in vb.net

```
Dim oWord_detail As New word.Application
Dim oDoc_detail As word.Document
oWord_detail.Visible = True
oDoc_detail = oWord_detail.Documents.Open("c:\integra-billing\integra-invoice-detail.docx", False, False)
```

I then use this line to add a new row to my word document

```
oDoc_detail.Tables(1).Rows.Add()
```

but when it runs, the above line shows the error:

```
The requested member of the collection does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

If table already exist try
oDoc_detail.Tables.Item(1).Rows.Add()

Then for add text to cell

```
Dim oWord_detail As New Word.Application
Dim oDoc_detail As Word.Document
oWord_detail.Visible = True
oDoc_detail = oWord_detail.Documents.Open("C:\Dati\Temp\test.docx", False, False)
oDoc_detail.Tables.Item(1).Rows.Add()

For r = 1 To 1  'your row
For c = 1 To 3
oDoc_detail.Tables.Item(1).Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "r" & r & "c" & c
Next
Next
```

Comment: there is a table, do i have to name it at all?

Comment: or give it an ID or somthing?

Comment: my table in word is inside a text box if that makes a difference ?

Comment: ok its out of the text box and now working. I have 3 columns in my table, how do i add data to each column?

Comment: and add data/text to the cells ?

Comment: I have add code to answer you must set your row number

Comment: whats the 1 to 1 and 1 to 3 ?

Comment: r for row, 1 write on the first row  while c are column. The result  of this code write on the first row r1c1 (in first column),r1c2 (second column) and so. Replace "r" & r & "c" & c whit your text

Comment: how do i insert different data in each column ?